# Bash: how to sum all columns excluding first column

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I need to sum all columns except the first column in a bash script. Please help as I am a beginner in scripting.

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5

APR     674070  672554  813355  809413
APR     674070  672554  813355  809413
APR     674070  672554  813355  809413
APR     375309  374466  460572  457776
APR     254161  253655  316361  314093
APR     234389  233874  295457  293222
APR     252482  251926  319122  316918
```

The output should look like below. The first column (i.e., APR) is same for all rows and I don't need to bother printing it.

The desired result is either

```
APR,3138551,3131583,3831577,3810248
```

or

```
3138551,3131583,3831577,3810248
```

I tried the command below, but I will require more than 20 columns and my method will be too lengthy with that many columns.

```
cat file | awk -F ',' '{a=a+$2}{b=b+$3}{c=c+$4}{d=d+$5} END { print "APR"","a","b","c","d }'
```

Let me know if exists an alternate way in bash.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F"," '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) sum[i]+=$i} END {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)if(i!=NF) printf "%d, ",sum[i]; else print sum[i]}' file
```

Comment: got blank output with this command         awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) sum[i]+=$i} END {for (i in sum) printf "%d ",sum[i]}' file

Comment: what is file delimiter? i thought it was tab. it works , if file has other separtor, just use it -F and delimiter

Comment: hi, delimiter is ",", so i used below command        cat test | awk -F "," '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) sum[i]+=$i} END {for (i in sum) printf "%d,",sum[i]}'      it works, but not printing in proper order.  output came as 3831577,3810248,3138551,3131583...                 where as correct output is 3138551,3131583,3831577,3810248

Comment: strange. for me works normally. do like this: awk -F"," '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) sum[i]+=$i} END {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%d ",sum[i]}' file

Comment: change `{for (i in sum) printf` to `{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf` looks like `i in sum` not give back the numbers in proper order. Possibly because the array not started from 0 but from 2. This will work also: `awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) sum[i-2]+=$i} END {for (i in sum) printf "%d ",sum[i]}' /file` we start array from index 0 with this: `sum[i-2]`